# Delete records from Elasticsearch by query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to delete specific date records from Elasticsearch. My query is the following:

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/twit/_query' -d '
{
    "filter" : {
            "range" : {
                "date_time" : { "from" : "2012-10-01 00:00:01", "to" : "2013-05-01 11:59:59"}
            }
        }
}'
```

but it is not deleting any records. so it is correct one or are there some other methods to delete records.

Answer (score 14):

Prior to 1.0, the delete by query does not use filters. The syntax goes directly to what is the "query" block in the search API. You need to use the [range query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/range-query/) instead.

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/twit/_query' -d '
{
    "range" : {
        "date_time" : { "from" : "2012-10-01 00:00:01", "to" : "2013-05-01 11:59:59"}
    }
}'
```

Comment: Or you can use a filtered_query and add a filter to it. The difference is that filters are cached and more performant.

Comment: I believe when you query to delete, you want to avoid using cached results.

Comment: Why? I guess it depends on the domain and the type of query you execute. It's not about having different results in this case, it's just about having results faster. But in some cases you do want to avoid caching heavy filters that you execute only once (you can do it with elasticsearch by the way).

Answer (score 7):

delete by query was deprecated since 2.0. Use scroll/scan to find all document ids you want to remove and call delete by ids

> Deprecated in 1.5.3.
>
> "Delete by Query will be removed in 2.0: it is problematic since it
>   silently forces a refresh which can quickly cause OutOfMemoryError
>   during concurrent indexing, and can also cause primary and replica to
>   become inconsistent. Instead, use the scroll/scan API to find all
>   matching ids and then issue a bulk request to delete them..

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/docs-delete-by-query.html

Also there is a [delete-by-query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/plugins-delete-by-query.html) plugin you can use.

Comment: The above was true at one point, but **delete by query is no longer deprecated.** In both v7 and v8 of ElasticSearch, the [docs for delete by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html) mention nothing about deprecation, so I guess it got un-deprecated at some point.