# Deleting all documents of a type and keeping the type

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to delete all indices of one type. Tried to execute this :

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/_query' -d '{"query": {"match_all": {}}}'
```

But this doesn't delete anything. The following query shows that my index is still there.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/_search' | json -i
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is the question actually `Deleting all DOCUMENTS of a type` (and keep the type)?

Comment: Yes otherwise I would have said "deleting a type", no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. I found this answer myself from this question [Delete records from Elasticsearch by query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676022/delete-records-from-elasticsearch-by-query)

The body to send with the request is **just** the query. So basically the right request is :

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/_query' -d '{"match_all": {}}'
```

Comment: Please note that body request needing to be nested in `query` is required for ES v1.x according to the Delete by Query documentation - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html Additionally, please be mindful of the note in the documentation about Delete by Query bypassing versioning and not being recommended for deleting "large chunks of data in an index".

Answer (score 2):

to delete the whole type you call `DELETE` on it

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/myindex/mytype
```

this deletes the type `mytype` in the index `myindex`.

be aware, that this deletes also any mappings etc with the type.  but i would consider this a more resource-friendly way (but can not proove it)

Comment: Yes, I had found this, but I don't want to delete the type.